# Typecast structure to byte array for later calls to fwrite

Tags: c, memory, layout, structure

My program will be frequently writing packets to disk ( fwrite() ), and sending them out via  ethernet ( send() ).  The packets are organized as structures like:

```
        struct PacketStruct{

              uint32_t Type;
              uint8_t * DataPtr;
              uint32_t Length;

        };
```

Memory is dynamically allocated, and the pointer is assigned to PacketStruct.DataPtr.

My question is, say I want to use another struct to organize the data that will eventually be pointed to by DataPtr.  For example:

```
        struct MyStruct{
              uint32_t A;
              uint8_t B;
              uint32_t C;
        };
```

then:

```
        NewPacket = malloc( sizeof(struct PacketStruct) );
        NewStruct = malloc( sizeof(struct MyStruct) );
        NewStruct->A = 1;
        NewStruct->B = 2;
        NewStruct->C = 3;
```

if I do:

```
        NewPacket->DataPtr = (uint8_t *) NewStruct;
        NewPacket->Length = sizeof( struct MyStruct);
```

Will I run into problems with structure padding etc. down the line when I do:

```
        fwrite( (void *) NewPacket->DataPtr, 1, (size_t) NewPacket->Length, fout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "problems". Here are the potential pitfalls I see:

1) `struct MyStruct` may contain padding after any member (and likely will after `B`). The memory covered by this padding will not be initialized by `malloc` or by your assignment statements. If you use `calloc` instead, these areas will be initialized to 0.

2) If you need to read the struct back in from the file, it will work in an identical implementation (the alignment of members is implementation defined). But as soon as you change architectures, compilers, or possibly even compiler options, you won't read back in what you wrote out.

3) Using casts prevents the compiler from doing any type-checking that could catch an error. If you have control over the definition of `struct PacketStruct` consider using a `union` of the possible types for `DataPtr`. This allows you to specify exactly which type you are expecting, treating the data as `uint8_t` when you just care about the bytes and as `struct MyStruct` when treating it as one.

4) More of a nitpick, but: the casts in your call to `fwrite` are not needed and could theoretically hide errors if the definition of those fields changes later.

Comment: Thanks! While I did know that structures were padded, I did not know that calling sizeof( struct StructX ) included the number of padding bytes... I see why this is a problem.